# Dealing with date-time string that has day of the week

Tags: r, regex, datetime

I have a date-time string that has day of the week and some meta-data in the string.

```
d <- "Fri, 14 Jul 2000 06:59:00 -0700 (PDT)"
```

I need to convert it into a date-time object (e.g. I have a column of these in a data.table) for further analysis. I have dealt with this using regexes to strip off meta-data from the string. *Is there a better approach?*

What I have is:

```
m <- regexpr("^\\w+,\\s+", d, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(d, m)
m <- regexpr("\\s-?\\d+\\s\\(\\w+\\)$", d, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(d, m)

ds <- sub("^\\w+,\\s+", "", d)
ds <- sub("\\s-?\\d+\\s\\(\\w+\\)$", "", ds)
```

Now I can convert this to date-time objects of class `Date`, `Posixlt` or `Posixct` for use in analysis.

```
dd <- strptime(ds, format="%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
dd <- as.Date(ds, format="%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
dd <- as.POSIXct(ds, format="%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: would the format of this string be consistent as you have shared here?

Comment: This `dd <- strptime(sub("^\\w+,", "", d), format="%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")` should work. I believe you just need to strip the weekday and comma from `d`. The `%z` in `format` converts the signed offset in hours and minutes from UTC, which is in `d`. Don't need to remove the training `"(PDT)"`

Comment: Thank you @aichao, That works. Up-voted.

Comment: Why wouldn't  `as.POSIXct(d, format = "%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")` work?

Comment: Close but not quite. Works for me _if_ I omit the trailing `%z`.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the [anytime package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) to help with (among other things) these silly format strings -- so it heuristically just tries a number of them (and focuses on sane ones).

The input you have here qualifies (and is in fact a pretty common form):

```
R> anytime("Fri, 14 Jul 2000 06:59:00 -0700 (PDT)")
[1] "2000-07-14 06:59:00 CDT"
R>
```

We do *not* currently try to capture the timezone offset information at the end, so you have to deal with that after the fact. The display is in CDT which is my local timezone.

There is some more information about [anytime on its webpage](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/anytime.html).

Answer (score 0):

assuming the format of string is going to be constant across your data :

```
time = trimws(unlist(strsplit(d, "[,-]"))[2])
#[1] "14 Jul 2000 06:59:00"
tz = unlist(strsplit(d, "[,-]"))[3]
tz = gsub("[^A-Z]", "", tz)
#[1] "PDT"

> as.Date(time, format = "%d %b %Y")
[1] "2000-07-14"
> as.POSIXct(time, format = "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S") #specify th etimezone with tz
[1] "2000-07-14 06:59:00 IST"
```